# Get data between dates in VARCHAR (Mysql and node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have searched on the already asked questions but I cant get this to work. What I am trying to do is to get all saved data between two dates (and if it contains the same email). The date is saved as strings (VARCHAR) in the following format: `15/10/2019`. I know it is bad practice to use VARCHAR as date database, but for now this is what I have to use.

I have tried the following but none of them works. For this first one I sometimes get some data, but it is not the correct dates. Probably because of the string format;

```
let sql = `SELECT reps FROM reps WHERE email = ? AND date >= ? and date <= ? ORDER BY date`;
```

To solve this I tried to use STR_TO_DATE but this just give me an empty array:

```
let sql = `SELECT reps FROM reps WHERE email = ? AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%/m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%/m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%/m/%Y')`;
```

Note that the question sign is used with node.js and stands for this (first question mark is user, next is date1 and last is date2):

```
connection.query(sql, [user, date1, date2], (error, result) => { ...
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In which format are you passing the date parameters to the query?

Comment: As strings: ’15/10/2019’

Comment: If so,  `STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%/m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%/m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%/m/%Y')` should work.

Comment: I thought so to, but for som reason I just get an empty array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in the `'%d/%/m/%Y'` if you try to remove the extra slash should be work.

Try with `'%d/%m/%Y'`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your are absolutely right! It was the typo error. Now it works fine! I spent a lot of time on this and the solution was that easy.